# Swift 4.2 Improve the "O" cost in an algorithm

Tags: swift, algorithm, mapreduce, reduce

Good morning everyone,

I'm trying to make a small algorithm with Swft 4.2 and have the lowest possible cost "O"

My question is given the code that I will pass to you. If you have any way to improve the cost of computing.

The algorithm what you have to do is:

- An array [Int] is passed to the "arrayMultiplication" function.
  Suppose it is [2,3,4,5]
- We will have to multiply all the elements for
  each position, except the same one. In this case it would be: [3x4x5,
  2x4x5, 2x3x5, 2x3x4] = [60, 40, 30, 24]

My code is the following:

```
import UIKit



class ViewController: UIViewController {



var arrayInts: [Int] = [2,3,4,5]

var arrayMultiplication: [Int] = []



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    arrayMultiplication = arrayMultiplication(array: &arrayInts)

    print("\(arrayMultiplication)")

}



func arrayMultiplication(array: inout [Int])-> [Int]{

    var arrayMult:[Int] = []

    for i in 0...array.count - 1 {

        let remove = array.remove(at: i)

        let mult = array.reduce (1, {$0 * $1})

        arrayMult.append(mult)

        array.insert(remove, at: i)

    }

    return arrayMult

}
}
```

The idea is to lower the "O" of this algorithm.

Thank you

Improve the "O" cost in an algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

```
var array = [2,3,4,5]

if let indexOf0 = array.firstIndex(of: 0) {
    array.remove(at: indexOf0)
    let product = array.reduce(1, *)
    var result = Array(repeating: 0, count: array.count + 1)
    result[indexOf0] = product
    print(result)
} else {
    let product = array.reduce(1, *)
    let result = array.map( {product/$0} )
    print(result)
}
```

- If array contains 0, calculate the product without zero and set all the other products as 0. (Note: If there is more than 1 zero, every element is set to zero.
- If it doesn't, calculate the product and iterate through the array once while dividing the product with the iterated element and store the result.

Thanks @Hamish for pointing out the oversight.

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau Don't accept the answer yet. There might be a better answer. This is one i could think of. Wait for other answers to come in.

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau i’ll update the answer when i’m back on my mac.

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau check the updated answer. This is still more optimal than your algorithm.

Comment: Perfect! Good job! This solution is perfect

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau glad it helped :)